# How to find in text numbers together with text

Tags: r, regex

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("Here an example 4V",
"Another 4 kg example",
"More s201000781840002x to check 95kwh"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How is it possible to keep all combinations which have a number only or with a letter into a different dataframe?

Example of expeded output:

```
id text
1  4V
2  4 kg
3  s201000781840002x
3  95kwh
```

Comment: 4 kg is kind of not a number and a letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach from the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(patterns = str_extract_all(text, pattern = "[^\\d\\W]*[0-9]+ ?[^\\d\\W]*")) %>%
  unnest_longer(patterns)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id text                                  patterns        
  <dbl> <chr>                                 <chr>           
1     1 Here an example 4V                    4V              
2     2 Another 4 kg example                  4 kg            
3     3 More s201000781840002x to check 95kwh s201000781840002x
4     3 More s201000781840002x to check 95kwh 95kwh
```

Edit: now with `[^\\d\\W]` to not match other neighboring number containing words.

Answer (score 1):

and in base R

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("Here an example 4V","Another 4 kg example","More s201000781840002x to check 95kwh"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test <- function(x) {
  matches <- gregexpr("\\d+\\s{0,1}\\w+",x)
  regmatches(x, m = matches)
}

output <- sapply(df$text, test)

>output
[1] "4V"

$`Another 4 kg example`
[1] "4 kg"

$`More s201000781840002x to check 95kwh`
[1] "201000781840002x" "95kwh"
```